# My while does not work properly to fetch the data in php from database

Tags: javascript, phpmyadmin, fetch, arr

```
<?php 
    require " require "dbconnect.php";

    $query="SELECT meta_title,published_date,number_of_pages,meta_description,meta_keywords,created_at FROM report";
    $res=MySQL_query($query) or die(MySQL_error());




            while($arr=MySQL_fetch_array($res)){
        $meta_title=$arr['meta_title'];
        $published_date=$arr['published_date'];
        $number_of_pages=$arr['number_of_pages'];
        $meta_description=$arr['meta_description'];
        $meta_keywords=$arr['meta_keywords'];
        $created_at=$arr['created_at'];



    }

    ?>";

    $query="SELECT meta_title,published_date,number_of_pages,meta_description,meta_keywords,created_at FROM report";
    $res=MySQL_query($query) or die(MySQL_error());




            while($arr=MySQL_fetch_array($res)){
        $meta_title=$arr['meta_title'];
        $published_date=$arr['published_date'];
        $number_of_pages=$arr['number_of_pages'];
        $meta_description=$arr['meta_description'];
        $meta_keywords=$arr['meta_keywords'];
        $created_at=$arr['created_at'];

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what is this require " require "dbconnect.php"; ? please know about where to use double quotes

Comment: require "dbconnect.php"; changes first line

Answer (score 0):

You have to establish database connection first like

```
$connection = mysql_connect('host','username','password','database');
```

then pass connection to `mysql_query` like this

```
mysql_query($connection,$query);
```